# SOLVED: How can I toggle between 2 colors

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am trying to toggle between 2 colors on h1 that is containing 2 words.
I am setting default 1 color for each word and trying to switch them by adding a class to them but it seems something it's wrong.

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#id1").toggleClass("class1");
  $("#id2").toggleClass("class2");
};
```

```css
#id1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.class1 {
  color: grey;
}

#id2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

.class2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="id1"> <span id="id2">bla</span> bla</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Any suggestions? 
LE: Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: It's all about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try introducing `!important` in both of your classes

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#id1").toggleClass("class1");
  $("#id2").toggleClass("class2");
};
```

```css
#id1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.class1 {
  color: grey !important;
}

#id2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

.class2 {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="id1"> <span id="id2">bla</span> bla</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: Just FYI that using `!important` really isn't good practice as it now makes it even harder to override that style, should you need to. Use selector specificity to override instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of CSS specificity

A style applied to an `id` is more specific than a style applied to a `class` even if you defined the latter after the former. You have to increase the specificity of your selectors when you toggle the class or make both of your selectors with the same specificity and take benefit of the cascade. A third way is to use `!important` but [I'd not use it](https://j11y.io/css/dont-use-important/) in this circumstance.

In the example below I changed your `id` selectors into `attribute` selector which have the same specificity of the `class` selector

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#id1").toggleClass("class1");
  $("#id2").toggleClass("class2");
};
```

```css
[id="id1"] {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.class1 {
  color: grey;
}

[id="id2"] {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

.class2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="id1"> <span id="id2">bla</span> bla</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: doing [id="id1"] and [id="id2"]  it's just toggle-ing between main black and the color classes.

Comment: @Psko What browser are you using?

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox. Tried on Chrome, same result.

Comment: It seems now it works...I guess something went wrong the 1st time

Answer (score 2):

Remove the color: blue from the id selector, is redudant.
You only need it in the 2 classes and toggle between them.

EDIT : For example

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#id1").toggleClass("class1").toggleClass("class2");
  $("#id2").toggleClass("class1").toggleClass("class2");
}
```

```css
#id1, #id2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.class1 {
  color: grey;
}

.class2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="id1" class="class1">
  <span id="id2" class="class2">bla</span> 
  bla
</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It only applies one class to each one and that's it. They don't toggle.

Comment: It seems not it works...I guess something went wrong the 1st time

Answer (score 2):

[Following MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) you should not use !important in your case

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#id1").toggleClass("class1");
  $("#id2").toggleClass("class2");
};
```

```css
#id1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

#id1.class1,
#id2.class1 {
  color: grey;
}

#id2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

#id1.class2,
#id2.class2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="id1"> <span id="id2">bla</span> bla</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox. Tried on Chrome, same result.

Comment: It seems now it works...I guess something went wrong the 1st time

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with CSS Specificity. Color applied using id cannot be overwritten by using class name.

It is always better to avoid `!important` whenever possible.

Instead of using `#id1`, try attribute selector like `[id="id1"]`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#id1").toggleClass("class1");
  $("#id2").toggleClass("class2");
};
```

```css
[id="id1"] {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.class1 {
  color: grey;
}

[id="id2"] {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

.class2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="id1"> <span id="id2">bla</span> bla</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox. Tried on Chrome, same result.

Comment: It seems not it works...I guess something went wrong the 1st time